# Problemas com multicones no menu android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estou tentando criar dois botões porém apenas está funcionando quando clico em um dos botões.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha activity esta de seguinte maneira:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
  <item
    android:id="@+id/comentar"
    android:icon="@drawable/comentarios"
    android:title="Verificar todos comentarios do estabelecimento"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
  <item
    android:id="@+id/favoritar"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favoritar"
    android:title="Adicionar estabelecimento aos favoritos"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Ja em minha classe esta assim:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_favoritar_restaurante, menu);
    menuItemCoracao = menu.getItem(0);

    if (restaurante.isFavorito()) {
        // Altera o icone para favoritado
        menuItemCoracao.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favoritado);
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (!restaurante.isFavorito()) {
        // Adiciona aos favoritos
        adicionarAosFavoritos();
    } else {
        // Remove
        removerDosFavoritos();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

A lógica do primeiro esta funcionando perfeitamente, porém agora preciso criar a logica do segundo, onde irei enviar para uma novo java que vai fazer a pesquisa de comentários daquele respectivo cliente.

Como fazer isto ?
Onde estou errando ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renan, você precisa verificar o ID clicado, exemplo:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.favoritar){
       if (!restaurante.isFavorito()) {
         // Adiciona aos favoritos
         adicionarAosFavoritos();
       } else {
         // Remove
         removerDosFavoritos();
       }
    }
    else if(id == R.id.comentar)
    {
       vaiProsComentarios();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: O problema é que agora esta alterando o icone errado

Comment: no item onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Tenta colocar 1 ao invés de 0 no ```menu.getItem(0);```

Comment: isto fiz aqui e deu certo

Comment: vlw, jaja aceito sua resposta